# Drone.IO – GitLab address with hosts file

Tags: gitlab, drone.io

I have a GitLab instance on a fixed internal IP, and configured the hosts file on the clients if a hostname which points to that IP.

But we are unable to make Drone work when using the hostname. We have Gitlab on port 80 and Drone on port 8000. It does work when it’s configured to the fixed ip:

Our compose file:

```
version: '2'
services:
    gitlab:
      image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest'
      restart: always
      environment:
        GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
          external_url 'http://our.host.name.com'
          gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 22
          # Add any other gitlab.rb configuration here, each on its own line
      ports:
        - '80:80'
        - '443:443'
        - '22:22'
      volumes:
        - '/srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab'
        - '/srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
        - '/srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab'

    drone-server:
      image: drone/drone:0.7.3
      links:
        - "gitlab:our.host.name.com"
      ports:
        - "8000:8000"
      volumes:
        - /home/drone:/var/lib/drone/
        - /home/drone/cache:/var/lib/drone/cache/
        - /home/foresight/keys:/var/lib/drone/keys
      environment:
        DRONE_OPEN: "true"
        DRONE_SERVER_ADDR: ":8000"
        DRONE_HOST: "http://our.host.name.com:8000"
        DRONE_ADMIN: <redacted>
        DRONE_GITLAB: "true"
        DRONE_GITLAB_URL: "http://our.host.name.com"
        DRONE_GITLAB_CLIENT: <redacted>
        DRONE_GITLAB_SECRET: <redacted>
        DRONE_SECRET: <redacted>
    drone-agent:
      image: drone/drone:0.7.3
      command: agent
      depends_on:
        - drone-server
      volumes:
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      environment:
        DRONE_SERVER: ws://drone-server:8000/ws/broker
        DRONE_DEBUG: "true"
        DRONE_SECRET: <redacted>
```

When i configure it this way, drone doesn’t seem to accept triggers from GitLab.

Naturally, i reset the drone cache, updated the callback url to use the domain name also, and re-activated the repositories.

i couldn’t find any log file for drone that provides insight on why the trigger fails.